Switching WhatsApp back and forth without sending "security code change" system message
I currently have 2 Android phones which, just for the sake of convenience, I routinely switch back and forth using the same WhatsApp number. One problem that I have is every time I switch my WhatsApp number to the other phone, it sends a "'security code change" to my contacts. My question is, how can I stop WhatsApp from sending a notification to my contacts while still being able to routinely switch my WhatsApp number between those 2 phones and still using the same number?
Because when that notification is sent, it implicitly tells my contacts that I'm switching phones and I for certain reasons don't want that. I'm asking this in the context of the current WhatsApp version (2.23.12.75) but also I don't really mind whether I have to use a modified version of WhatsApp in order to achieve this feat. Is there such a modified/3rd-party WhatsApp app that can do that?
Also, using the current WhatsApp, does it matter whether I have saved my contact number to my WhatsApp or not? Let's say, if I didn't save it, but on that phone, I have chatted with that contact previously, will it still send him/her that notification when I switch between phones?

WhatsApp Web
WhatsApp Web is the most secure way and the one that WhatsApp suggests for these kinda situations.
This is the official way to use WhatsApp on multiple devices.
You can link your WhatsApp account to up to four devices simultaneously, including phones(but to mention that you should put your browser to desktop site mode).
This is the official website: [web.whatsapp.com][1]
Steps (if you wish to test):

First login to your WhatsApp account on the app and rather the most used phone.

On the second phone open the WhatsApp Web website and before you do anything put to desktop mode.

Now do regular steps of connecting your account using the QR scanner on the Main phone to scan the QR code on the second device.

For easier access try to add the web page to your Home screen (install app on some devices and Add to Home screen & like these)


Unfortunately the UI will be bothering (it is for me as i use this method till this day) , but it works.
About your last question, to my knowledge if using the app on both device yes even if you haven't saved your contact number in WhatsApp, it will still send the "security code change" notification to your contacts if you switch WhatsApp between your two phones
But if using the web method , it's less likely to trigger a "security code change" notification to that contact cuz it's kinda of an extension. But i most mention that This is based on general understanding. WhatsApp's behavior can sometimes be unpredictable and even new Updates might change the apps behavior in this matter.
small update: i just tested the web method and there was no "security code change" notification on the other contacts of mine (i checked on several devices).
wish i helped
[1]: https://web.whatsapp.com
